# How to write correct XPath or CSS?

Tags: javascript, xpath, checkbox, automation, protractor

My HTML is:

```
  <div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="376" col-id="0" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-focus ag-cell-range-selected ag-cell-range-selected-1" style="width: 77px; left: 0px;">
    <span ref="eCellWrapper" class="ag-cell-wrapper">
      <span class="ag-selection-checkbox">
        <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked"></span>
        <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-unchecked ag-hidden"></span>
        <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-indeterminate ag-hidden"></span>
      </span>
      <span ref="eCellValue" class="ag-cell-value"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <span ref="eCellWrapper" class="ag-cell-wrapper">
    <span class="ag-selection-checkbox">
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked"></span>
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-unchecked ag-hidden"></span>
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-indeterminate ag-hidden"></span>
    </span>
    <span ref="eCellValue" class="ag-cell-value"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked"></span>
  <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-unchecked ag-hidden"></span>
  <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-indeterminate ag-hidden"></span>
  <span class="ag-selection-checkbox">
    <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked"></span>
    <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-unchecked ag-hidden"></span>
    <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-indeterminate ag-hidden"></span>
  </span>
  <span ref="eCellValue" class="ag-cell-value"></span>
  <span ref="eCellWrapper" class="ag-cell-wrapper">
    <span class="ag-selection-checkbox">
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked"></span>
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-unchecked ag-hidden"></span>
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-indeterminate ag-hidden"></span>
    </span><span ref="eCellValue" class="ag-cell-value"></span>
  </span>
```

How to write correct identifier for clicking checkbox.I have row with informations, that row has checkbox I need to click to that checkbox.

This is my XPath?

```
var checkbox= element(by.css('div.ag-body-container>div[row id="0"]>div[col-id="0"]'));
browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(checkbox), 5000);
checkbox.click();
```

It is pass, but it did not click right checkbox.It is just highlighted  whole row.

My HTML:

```
  <div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="376" col-id="0" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-focus ag-cell-range-selected ag-cell-range-selected-1" style="width: 77px; left: 0px;"><span ref="eCellWrapper" class="ag-cell-wrapper"><span class="ag-selection-checkbox"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked"></span><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-unchecked ag-hidden"></span><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-indeterminate ag-hidden"></span></span><span ref="eCellValue" class="ag-cell-value"></span></span></div>
  <span ref="eCellWrapper" class="ag-cell-wrapper">
    <span class="ag-selection-checkbox">
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked"></span>
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-unchecked ag-hidden"></span>
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-indeterminate ag-hidden"></span>
    </span>
    <span ref="eCellValue" class="ag-cell-value"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked"></span>

  <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-unchecked ag-hidden"></span>
  <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-indeterminate ag-hidden"></span>
  <span class="ag-selection-checkbox">
    <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked"></span>
    <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-unchecked ag-hidden"></span>
    <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-indeterminate ag-hidden"></span>
  </span>
  <span ref="eCellValue" class="ag-cell-value"></span>
  <span ref="eCellWrapper" class="ag-cell-wrapper">
    <span class="ag-selection-checkbox">
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked"></span>
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-unchecked ag-hidden"></span>
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-indeterminate ag-hidden"></span>
    </span>
    <span ref="eCellValue" class="ag-cell-value"></span>
  </span>
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are looking for. There is no XPath here, nor should there be since this isn't XML. CSS can be used to select elements for styling and the DOM API can be used in JavaScript to query for elements. But, it is unclear what you actually want to do.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I want to give correct locator and click  element .

Comment: Click ***which*** element?

Comment: @ScottMarcus     this element     <div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="376" col-id="0" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-focus ag-cell-range-selected ag-cell-range-selected-1" style="width: 77px; left: 0px;"><span ref="eCellWrapper" class="ag-cell-wrapper"><span class="ag-selection-checkbox"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked ag-hidden"></span><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-unchecked"></span><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-indeterminate ag-hidden"></span></span><span ref="eCellValue" class="ag-cell-value"></span></span></div>

Comment: @ScottMarcus this is my css element(by.css('div.ag-body-container>div[row id="0"]>div[col-id="0"]')); it just highlighted,did not click. Probably  my css is not specified

Comment: @ScottMarcus   Failed: document is not defined
  Stack:
    ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: Make sure you add this code in a `<script>` element just before the closing `body` tag. The code does work as you can see by running it here. `document` always exists in a web page. If it's not working for you, something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var css_locator = 'div.ag-body-container > div[row-id="0"] > div[col-id="0"] .ag-selection-checkbox :not(.ag-hidden)';

var checkbox= element(by.css(css_locator));
browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(checkbox), 5000);
checkbox.click();
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: It helped.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `document.querySelector()` that isolates the element by some unique factor. I assume that the `comp-id` value is unique. But, you should know that `comp-id` is an invalid attribute.

```js
let theDiv = document.querySelector("div[comp-id='376']");

theDiv.addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log("element clicked!");
});

theDiv.click();
```

```html
  <div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="376" col-id="0" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-focus ag-cell-range-selected ag-cell-range-selected-1" style="width: 77px; left: 0px;"><span ref="eCellWrapper" class="ag-cell-wrapper"><span class="ag-selection-checkbox"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked"></span><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-unchecked ag-hidden"></span><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-indeterminate ag-hidden"></span></span><span ref="eCellValue" class="ag-cell-value"></span></span></div>
  <span ref="eCellWrapper" class="ag-cell-wrapper">
    <span class="ag-selection-checkbox">
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked"></span>
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-unchecked ag-hidden"></span>
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-indeterminate ag-hidden"></span>
    </span>
    <span ref="eCellValue" class="ag-cell-value"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked"></span>

  <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-unchecked ag-hidden"></span>
  <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-indeterminate ag-hidden"></span>
  <span class="ag-selection-checkbox">
    <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked"></span>
    <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-unchecked ag-hidden"></span>
    <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-indeterminate ag-hidden"></span>
  </span>
  <span ref="eCellValue" class="ag-cell-value"></span>
  <span ref="eCellWrapper" class="ag-cell-wrapper">
    <span class="ag-selection-checkbox">
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked"></span>
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-unchecked ag-hidden"></span>
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-indeterminate ag-hidden"></span>
    </span>
    <span ref="eCellValue" class="ag-cell-value"></span>
  </span>
```